# Image_view frozen image

Tags: ros, image-view, ros-indigo, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using image_view on a Jetson tegra - Ubuntu 14.04 Indigo.  When I run Image view, I get a frozen image (One frame). Usually I get no error messages, occasionally I dee [ 4002.992926] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).  in dmesg.  Topics are being echo'ed.

If I run image-view on a remote laptop(Indigo 14.04), I get a moving image, but multiple error messages of:

QMetaMethod::Invoke: Unable to invoke methods with return values in queued connections

Also I can't kill the process with control-c I need to kill the terminal session.

Further because image_view works just fine when the remote node is running hydro on an AMD-64 running Ubuntu 12.04.

Guess I need a witch doctor and a rattle to figure out this one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197810/image_view-frozen-image/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question might be related. http://answers.ros.org/question/193876/image_view-freeze-after-3-seconds/

The solution to the linked question has been implemented, and will be present in the next sync.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0